# How to use a custom sampler in your Flux.jl data loader?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am trying to load in just part of a dataset and also try out steps like random sampling to see how this impacts my models performance. I was reading the Flux.jl docs here: https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/data/dataloader/ and trying to see if I can define my own custom sampler but it does not show anything. Is it possible to define this sort of sampler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dataloader is just a type for which the *Base.iterate* method has been overloaded

```
@propagate_inbounds function Base.iterate(d::DataLoader, i=0)
...
```

so you should be able to do the same, I would imagine inheriting from the **dataloader** type and overloading *Base.iterate* for your own type with whatever functionality you want should cut it. Just make sure to return a tuple containing (batch, next_index). See the source code for [Flux.Dataloader](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/master/src/data/dataloader.jl) for more info on that.